# How to handle tab key using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one form and on tab key press fields should be focus rotate 
be clear. Please see following code.

[Jsfiddle run](https://jsfiddle.net/mw70con3/5/)

```js
    $('#e').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 9)
            $("#a").focus();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" id = "a" name="a" /><br/>
<input type = "text" id = "b" name="b" /><br/>
<input type = "text" id = "c" name="c" /><br/>
<input type = "text" id = "d" name="d" /><br/>
<input type = "text" id = "e" name="e" /><br/>
```

> when it go to field 'e' it directly go to 'a' that is ok . but it not wait at 'e' no need to get chance to enter in field 'e'

Please guide me.

Comment: I can't see any code...

Comment: apologies . pl check now

Comment: Because you set it so!

Comment: I don't get your English

Comment: Mr Alien. I m new in this world . It will improve , everybody go through this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `keyup` event occurs *after* it has already moved the focus to the next field.

You need to do it on the `keydown` event instead:

```js
    $('#e').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 9){
            $("#a").focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" id = "a" name="a" /><br/>
<input type = "text" id = "b" name="b" /><br/>
<input type = "text" id = "c" name="c" /><br/>
<input type = "text" id = "d" name="d" /><br/>
<input type = "text" id = "e" name="e" /><br/>
```

The reason `e.preventDefault()`, or simply `return false;` is needed, is that the `keydown` will still move from the *current focused control* (i.e. from `#a` to `#b`)

If you want it more generic, forget the IDs and use `:last` and `:first` selectors

e.g.

```
    $('input:last').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 9){
            $("input:first").focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks this what i want

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a keydown event, not keyup. The default behaviour of tab key is moving the next target on keydown as well.

```
$('#e').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#a").focus();
    }
});
```

See the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mw70con3/5/).

Comment: Just what we need... A third identical answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much i tried keydown but not "e.preventDefault" :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice others were responding as well.

Comment: @frontsideair hello , i tried your code but main problem is that when i want to write something on "e" field . it will not allow  i type any key it will fire this function . pl help

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07jh6cow/), you need to put preventDefault in if block.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your listened event and don't forget to stop event propagation

```
$('#e').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 9) {
        $("#a").focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mw70con3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer to a correct one.
Check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mw70con3/15/)

```
//prevent default behavior
$(document).on('keydown', 'input[type="text"]', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 9) {
      e.preventDefault();  
    }      
});

$(document).on('keyup', 'input[type="text"]', function(e) {

    if(e.keyCode === 9) {
        if($(this).index()+1 < $(this).siblings().length) {
            $(this).siblings().eq($(this).index()+1).focus();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings().first().focus();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You simply cannot change focus in a `keyup` event. It will not work as the focus was already moved during `keydown`! Sorry -1.

Comment: You are right of course. You need to disable auto tab indexing by preventing default on keydown.

Comment: Overly complicated (replacing the default tab behavior for all inputs and managing tabbing manually), but it does *work* now :) https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w9ew23yq/ DV removed as promised :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks :) I do not like it either, but I thought that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: When in doubt it's only the *end result* that the OP wants. Start by figuring out what the end result is that they *actually want* :)

Comment: It is working but i can't able to write anything in any text field so it now worth

Comment: As it is now it disables the default functionality of all keys. Check my updated answer for disabling only the default behavior of tab.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one that would work on indefinite set of inputs. Also, this doesn't rely on IDs.

```js
var $inputs = $('input');
var $lastInput = $inputs.last();
$inputs.keydown(function (e) {
    if ( e.which === 9 && $lastInput.is(":focus") ) {
        $inputs.first().focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" /><br/>
<input type = "text" /><br/>
<input type = "text" /><br/>
<input type = "text" /><br/>
<input type = "text" /><br/>
<input type = "text" /><br/>
<input type = "text" /><br/>
<input type = "text" /><br/>
<input type = "text" /><br/>
<input type = "text" /><br/>
```

Comment: but problem is that it is not my requirement . i want to ristrict certtain text field  that only rotate not all input